# How to set up geotools/geoscript for logstash on an offline linux box?

Tags: logstash, geoserver, wms, geotools

I'm currently a 2nd year comp sci student working out an independent project as a trial for my final year work, and have been having some issues with configuring an ELK stack to work with geoserver logs using the contrib wms.rb filter. The main purpose of what I'm trying to do is have the bounding box of a WMS request sent to elasticsearch as a geo_shape.

I haven't been able to work out how to use the geoscript plugin, given that the only help I've seen has been variations of "...using the geoscript (Gem/Wrapper) to the Geotools java library..." I was wondering if anyone could give me an idiots guide to setting up the geotools java library, and then how to actually get geoscript from it?
I've tried the official geotools installation guide and it doesn't seem particularly suitable for what I'm trying to do.

Do I have to have maven installed for this? I only meant it to be a small piece of work so was hoping to do it without having to learn how to use maven.
I've attempted a few workarounds and none of them have come to anything. I was hoping there would be a more straightforward solution given that when I can't find an existing forum thread for something its usually because I'm missing something obvious.

(I'm having to work on a linux (centos 6) box with no internet connection, just to make this even easier.)
I'm not totally computer illiterate but the simpler the response the better.

Cheers for any help, I'm at my wits' end.

And apologies if this was the wrong place to post it, it's on several forums as I've tried to hedge my bets.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the home of [GeoScript](http://geoscript.org/) shows where to download the 4 different versions:

1. Python
2. JavaScript
3. Scala
4. Groovy

From your question it's not clear which one you are using but each of them should download all the necessary GeoTools jars that you need to get going.